# Create hyperlink to folder if folder with same name exists (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have an excel document and column A is just a list of numbers, my case numbers at work. These numbers a flowed in regularly from another document and are regularly updated. I have a folder called "cases" within which are all the different subfolders containing the case details and documents of each case.

At the moment I currently have to manually hyperlink each case number (from column A) to its respective folder (which is always named identically to the case number from column A). I want a script that looks at all the numbers in column A each time I open the excel document, scans through my "cases" folder, and if it finds a sub folder with an identical name/number it creates the hyperlink to the folder in the excel cell in column A. Clear as mud?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hyperlink method:

```
=HYPERLINK("C://file/folder/"&A4,A4)
```

Where the first A4 would refer to the cell that contains the cell number and the second A4 would refer to the value of the hyperlink that would show up. You could remove the second A4 if you would like the path to be shown in your cell instead.